# Can I query the remote for the currently used submodule commit id?

Tags: git

I have a repository with submodules.
I would like to be able to see which commit of the submodule is being used in that repo.

`git submodule status` will only work for the above when submodules are updated locally.

I would rather not  `checkout master; git pull; git submodule update; git submodule status`, if possible.  Would be better if I could use the remote's url, much like `git ls-remote`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query the remote server for the contents of the repository without fetching first, and submodule hashes are considered part of the contents of the repository.  They're stored in tree objects, so it's necessary to pull down the relevant objects first.

You don't have to check out the branch, though.  You can do `git fetch origin && git rev-parse --verify origin/master:path/to/submodule` to fetch the objects for the remote and list the hash.